# Django 2.2: TemplateDoesNotExist at/ error

Tags: python, django, templates, debugging

Even after following the suggestions given in the rest of the answers to similar questions I am unable to resolve this error.

[image]

Comment: Error saying that you're trying to extend `base.html` from `blog` app where this template was not found (note last line of path's Django tried to search in)

Comment: Have you base.html file? and is it under the blog folder?

Comment: yes, the base.html file is in the blog folder inside the template directory.

Comment: There is a space after base.html, remove that space.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
there should not be any space between Inverted commas.
This should work, if html file is in correct folder.
:)